# substring function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table color and values are like this

```
Color   
D-E   
D-015   
E-0157  
WWW-014     
FER-014     
T-015
```

I am expecting the output like

```
Color
D-E   
D   
E   
WWW     
FER    
T
```

If i try

```
select substring(color,1,1) from Color
```

it is giving me

Color

```
D    
D   
E   
W   
F   
T
```

How to get the expected output.

Comment: Why would you get `'D-E'`?

Comment: Because it is 1 type of color in system and cannot remove. And for D-015 is something we altered in the system. But while displaying the color it should only show D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to get everything up to the first hyphen (assuming that `'D-E'` as a desired result is a typo):

```
select left(color, charindex('-', color) - 1)
```

If you want to be safe, in case the color does not have a hyphen:

```
select left(color, charindex('-', color + '-') - 1)
```

If you actually want everything before the first hyphen followed by a number, use `patindex()`:

```
select left(color, patindex('%-[0-9]%', color + '-0') - 1)
```

Comment: I updated my question, i missed on 1 scenario. Basically i want to remove -015 from D-015. I want to remove the numbers from the color

Comment: I ran your query and fom D-E it is showing D-. I want it to show D-E and for D-015 it is showing D-

Comment: Yes your 3rd answer is correct. Thanx Gordon. patindex does the trick